# Как в гонках привязать машину к камере в pygame?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

Для того чтобы расширить игровое пространство, в своей игре я пытаюсь использовать камеру, однако, я так и не смог разобраться как привязать машину к камере:

```
class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, wigth, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = pygame.Rect(0,0, wigth, height)
    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)
 def camera_func(camera, target_rect):
    l= -target_rect.x + W/2
    t= -target_rect.y+  H/2
    w, h = camera.width, camera.height
    l= min(0, l)
    l=max(-(camera.width-W),l)
    t=max(-(camera.height-H),t)
    t=min(0,t)
    return pygame.Rect(l,t,w,h)
class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.player_img = player_img.convert()
        self.player_img.set_colorkey(black)
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(pos)
        self.angle = 180
        self.speed = 10
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.player_img, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(pos))
    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_a] and keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.angle -=10
        elif keys[pygame.K_d] and keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_d] and keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.angle +=10
        dirvec = pygame.math.Vector2(0, self.speed).rotate(self.angle)
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
             self.pos = self.pos + dirvec
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.pos = self.pos - dirvec
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.player_img, -self.angle)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))
#Мои попытки привязать одно к другому
avt=Car((600, 400))
lvl_w=1200
lvl_h=1200
camera =  Camera(camera_func, lvl_w, lvl_h)
screen.blit(avt.image, avt.rect)
avt.update()
camera.update(avt)
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем я так до конца и не понял, почему я не могу привязать камеру способом который весит у меня в вопросе. Однако проблему я смог решить используя вектора.

```
avt=Car((W/2, H/2))
camera=pygame.math.Vector2(W/2, H/2)
heading = avt.pos - camera
camera += heading * 0.05
offset = -camera + pygame.math.Vector2(W/2, H/2)
suma= avt.rect.topleft+offset
screen.blit(avt.image, suma )
```

Теперь камера привязана к машине, только советую заранее нарисовать уровень. Для отрисовки я так же использовал вектора

```
for p in entities:
    topleft=p.rect.topleft+offset
    screen.blit(p.image, (topleft,p.rect.size))
```